# Laravel 5 hasManyThrough issue

Tags: php, laravel-5, has-many-through

I am five days into Laravel and after hours of watching Jeffrey Way I decided to delve into building an app to learn. I am stuck at the point of working with tables in a hasManyThrough layout and a not found class. Any help is appreciated.

I am trying to retrieve:

**A distinct list of cable specifications that are allowed with a selected cable_installation_method**

Thanks!

**TABLE 1: cable_specifications**

```
cable_specifications_id (REPEATS)
other_columns...
```

**TABLE 2: cable_installation_methods**

```
cable_installation_methods_id (UNIQUE)
other_columns...
```

**TABLE 3: cable_installations (PIVOT)**

```
cable_specifications_id (REPEATS)
cable_installation_methods_id (REPEATS)
```

My classes are:

```
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model as Eloquent;

class CableInstallation extends Eloquent {

    protected $table = 'cable_installations';

    protected $fillable = [];

    public function cable_installation_method()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('CableInstallationMethod');
    }

    public function cable_specification()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('CableSpecifications');
    }

    public function voltage_drop()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('CableVoltageDrop');
    }

}


class CableInstallationMethod extends Eloquent {

    protected $table = 'cable_installation_methods';

    protected $fillable = [];

    public function CableInstallation()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('CableInstallation');
    }

    public function CableSpecByInstall()
    {
        return $this->hasManyThrough('CableSpecification', 'CableInstallation', 'cable_specifications_id', 'cable_installations_id')
                    ->distinct();
    }

}

class CableSpecification extends Eloquent {

    protected $table = 'cable_specifications';

    protected $fillable = [];

    public function CableInstallFromSpec()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('CableInstallation');
    }

}
```

In my controller, I call this function per below:

```
public function VoltageDropLoad()
{
    $InstallationMethods = CableInstallationMethod::all();

    $CableSelected =  CableInstallationMethod::where("cable_installation_methods_id", 1)->firstOrFail();

    $CableTypes = $CableSelected->CableSpecByInstall()->toJson();

    return view('pages.voltcalc', compact('InstallationMethods', 'CableTypes', 'CableTypes'));
}
```

I end up with this error:

> FatalErrorException in Model.php line 911:
>   Class 'CableInstallation' not found

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't actually fetched your "cable" yet. Try:

```
$CableSelected = CableInstallationMethod::where("cable_installation_methods_id", 1)->firstOrFail();
```

Just to clear this up a little. Your cable installations is not really a pivot in this case (by my reckoning). It is just another model that contains relations to the other two. A pivot table will usually not have a model and is used for many to many relationships.

For example; something like `cable_installers` for `cable_installations` where you can have multiple installers work on cable installations. In this case, "installers" will be a model (with a table), "installations" will be a model (table already provided) and `installations_installers` will be a pivot table that stores the relation.

Comment: Hi @Scopey thanks for the reply. I added the"->get()" but I still get an error on the "hasManyThrough" function of "FatalErrorException in PagesController.php line 25: Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::CableSpecByInstall()"

Comment: Sorry, my fault - It's returning a "collection" which is essentially a glorified array of results. Use `->firstOrFail()` instead of `->get()`. I'll update my answer. You can just use `->first()` if you want it to not throw an exception if there is nothing matching your query.

Comment: Hi @Scopey, thanks for the second reply! The code seems to have moved forward to a "class not found" issue when I made your suggested change.